# Probability of 2 events.

Tags: probability

We know that probability is given in binary variables, so '$0$' means that event does not occur and '$1$' means that event occurs.
We also know that
P(Y=1)=0.6
P(Y=0)=0.4
P(X=1|Y=1)=0.2
P(X=1|Y=0)=0.5

Is there a way to find P(X=0|Y=0) with the given information?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/620957) on how to write a good question. In particular, what have you tried? How are you stuck? You will find that showing honest effort on your part will attract far more help on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X=0|Y=0)=1-P(X=1|Y=0)=0.5$.